# How to prove that $E\subset [0,1]$ with some property is countable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ be a subset of $[0,1]$.
For every sequence $(a_n)$ who's elements are in $E$ and different from each other, the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.
prove that $E$ is countable.

I've been stuck on this question for days, and i honestly have no idea where to start. I'd be very grateful if someone could push me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$E\setminus\{0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n,$$where $$E_n=\{x\in E:x>1/n\}.$$

Comment: The classic answer :)  Sometimes I begin to wonder where this method originated and to whom it was first attributed.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) just one question, im a bit new to this subject - is it correct that the continuation of the proof would be to show that En is finite for every n?

Comment: @BigbearZzz I believe it was Archimedes, in a still-undiscovered manuscript.

Comment: @NoamDolovich Yes.

Comment: im a bit confused - would the result be the same if we replaced the condition series(an) converges with an --> 0?

Comment: @NoamDolovich Yes.